# AES-GCM encryption compatibility between android/java and web/javascript

Tags: android, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

**Problem definition:** I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt data on Android platform and on web interchangeably. Right now, my solution is working platform specifically i.e web encrypted data can be decrypted on web only and failing on android with `AEADBadTagExcepton:mac check in GCM failed` and similarly android encrypted data fails to decrypt on web. I have spent a lot of hours but could not find solution yet.

does AES-GCM somehow varies on android and web? despite key and text being same, the encrypted output is different for android and web
Im using `AES-GCM` algorithm for encryption, also refer to code below

**Android code**

```
fun encryptAES(textToEncrypt: String, secretKey: ByteArray?, iv: ByteArray): String? {
    return try {
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(secretKey, 0, secretKey?.size!!, "AES")
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
        val parameterSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv) //128 bit auth tag length
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, parameterSpec)
        val cipherText = cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        encodeToBase64String(cipherText)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ""
    }
}

fun decryptAES(cipherString: String?, secretKeyBytes: ByteArray?, iv: ByteArray?): String? {
    return try {
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(secretKeyBytes, 0, secretKeyBytes?.size!!, "AES")
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
        val cipherMessage = decodeBase64(cipherString)
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)) //128 is tag length which is also same on web side
        val plainTextByteArray = cipher.doFinal(cipherMessage)
        String(plainTextByteArray, Charsets.UTF_8)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        ""
    }
}
```

**web code using SubtleCrypto API**

```
crypto.subtle.encrypt({name: "aes-gcm", iv: iv}, secretKey, plainText)
crypto.subtle.decrypt({name: "aes-gcm", iv: iv}, secretKey, cipherText)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that. For the plaintext `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` and the key `100f0e0d0c0b0a090807060504030201` as well as the IV `0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f10` (both as hex-values) I get for _both_, Android and web, as ciphertext: Base64: `X8qM2OzDSsQnhBKRPuDHEXSoHBf0neO+9IHbpXEN7QGVIH/GrDU2K8BUyoZSINQ7kJGogms/yo638yI=` and Hex: `5fca8cd8ecc34ac4278412913ee0c71174a81c17f49de3bef481dba5710ded0195207fc6ac35362bc054ca865220d43b9091a8826b3fca8eb7f322`. Compare, which of your output differs.

Comment: actually both of them are differing, 

in android im getting this -> `VFDbNGRrO1ffWJsOQlezzQxAHKboNYXJW1osKxi5oPXTCCyK_PHZSseLseHZXcIzDxypGmBwOhCj0gE=`

in web ->
`s3in6SyG76qf1LvotcwkOjh-ruGt9gdJ1DrAAaKIHNTC3eBTmH_65i59CFqVdJlN9N6V1VV4krUQS14=`

FYI, im executing same code for android and web given in question e.g.
`AesUtil.encryptAES("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "100f0e0d0c0b0a090807060504030201".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), "0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f10".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))`

Comment: I specified key and IV as _hexadecimal_ string, i.e. the initialization in Kotlin for the key could be performed e.g. with
`val key: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(0x10,0x0f,0x0e,0x0d,0x0c,0x0b,0x0a,0x09,0x08,0x07,0x06,0x05,0x04,0x03,0x02,0x01)` and for the IV with `val iv: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0a,0x0b,0x0c,0x0d,0x0e,0x0f,0x10)`. Try this for the Kotlin-code.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the implementation of the Android-methods themselves, but somewhere else, e.g. the proper initialization of plaintext, key and/or IV. If the issue persists, you should edit your question and post the _full_ code for _both_, Android and Web Crypto.

Comment: We found the issue, we were passing ArrayBuffer as iv, but we needed to pass int8Array from arrayBuffer object. thanks a lot for inputs @Topaco